# if elseif else preg_match windows location

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match

I am creating a form where i want that if someone answer is a certain number like 2 or 7 the will be directed to diffrent pages.

I searched online and came up making this.

```
<?php
// define variables
$name "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (!preg_match("/^3/",$name)) {
      echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://google.nl/">";
 } elseif (!preg_match("/^9/",$name)) {
      echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://osm.nl/">";
 }
   else {
      echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://facebook.nl/">";
}

}
?>
```

First i tested it by creating a validation form, which works fine. Trough research i edited the code. But now when i tried to open the page it is point blank.

How do i fix it that i can redirect the inputs

Comment: `echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh"` ... turn error reporting on and you'll be able to debug it

Comment: `preg_match()` is a hammer to crack a nut. try `if ($name == 3) {`

Comment: And where does `$name` come from anyway

Comment: Use single quotes intead of double quotes to delimitate strings that have double qutotes inside them.

Comment: I am new to php so i dont know much. I looked up how to add a error reporting and from what i found the user get noticed of the reporting. How do i get around that

Comment: And if `$name = "";` whats the point of testing against anything. You set it to an empty string so rest of code is irrelevant

Comment: i want to test if the input first character has a certain number

Comment: $name comes from this script

<form method="post" action="<?php($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would Use Switch Statement and the php header function to redirect

In the file your posting the form to:

```
$page = $_POST['name'];
switch($page)
{
    case 2:
        header("Location: http://www.google.com");
        break;
    case 7:
        header("Location: http://www.facebook.com");
        break;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: maybe switching on 2 and 7 would make a better answer as that **was** in the question

Comment: I tried this code, but the it redirect straight to header 0, without seeing the page with input

Comment: The point is that i want to test the input first character has a certain number and then redirect

Comment: If you only wish to use the first character of the input. Then you can you can use `substr($page, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

So here are all your errors:
Line 3 :`$name ""`: Where is the "="?
Line 7, 9, 12: `echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh"`: If you haven't figured that youself, consider using header as @NathanLeadill said.